# how to import css style for antd card?

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I'm importing from the right place. Can we do it this way or we have to add styles along with card ?

positions.styles.css :

```
.display{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 90%;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 23px;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

main component:

```
import { Card,Space } from 'antd';
import {Typography } from 'antd';
import cat from  '../../assets/cat.png';
import ape from '../../assets/apes-together.gif'
import styles from './positions.styles.css';
const { Title } = Typography;



function Positions(props) {

    return (
        <div className="content-container">
            <h3 className="content-header" style={{padding: "2%", fontSize: '40px'}}>Positions</h3>

            <div class="row" style={{display:'flex'}}  >
            <Space>

            <Card  className={styles.display} title={<Title level={2}>Tech Excellence</Title>}    >
              <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque lobortis arcu dui, et maximus nunc feugiat eu. Proin in dui eget ligula dictum volutpat sed vitae neque. In rhoncus quam sapien, eget dapibus arcu malesuada vel. Sed iaculis sapien lorem, sed congue dui mollis non.</p>
            </Card>

            <Card title={<Title style={{padding: "2px", marginTop: 20}} level={2}>Collaboration</Title>} style={{overflow: 'hidden', width: '90%', fontSize: '23px', backgroundImage:`url(${ape})`}} >
              <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque lobortis arcu dui, et maximus nunc feugiat eu. Proin in dui eget ligula dictum volutpat sed vitae neque. In rhoncus quam sapien, eget dapibus arcu malesuada vel. Sed iaculis sapien lorem, sed congue dui mollis non. </p>
            </Card>
            
        
            </Space>
            </div>
 
            
        </div>
    );
}

export default Positions;
```

first card is not getting styled, second one is.

Comment: Check CSS Module Import Path or Class Names in CSS Module. or Applying CSS Module Styles

Comment: using .module.css worked . thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my antd app I use TS files to handle css styles on each component and it works very well. Here's a little example:

```
// folder tree
- root folder
  - components
    - card component
      - index.tsx
      - styles.ts
    - other component
      ....

  - index.tsx // root component
```

Card component `styles.tsx` file:

```
import { CSSProperties } from 'react'
import { theme as antdTheme } from 'antd'

type StylesType = {
  Container: CSSProperties
  OtherStyle: (active: boolean) => CSSProperties
}

/**
 * Styles
 *
 * @return {StylesType} styles
 */
function Styles(): StylesType {
  const { useToken } = antdTheme
  const { token: theme } = useToken()

  const Container: CSSProperties = {
    backgroundColor: theme.colorPrimary
  }

  function OtherStyle(active: boolean): CSSProperties {
    backgroundColor: active? theme.colorPrimary : 'black'
  }

  return {
    Container,
    OtherStyle
  }
}

export default Styles
```

Then import and use it inside card component `index.tsx` file:

```
import Styles from './styles'

...

function Card() {
  const S = Styles()
  
  const divActive = true/false
  ...
  
  return (
    <Card styles={S.Container}>
      <div styles={S.OtherStyle(divActive)}> test </div>
    </Card>
  )
}
```

Hope this helps